# What does the index parameter of std::ios_base::register_callback do?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/register_callback/

I thought that the `index` would control the order in which callbacks are fired, but that doesn't seem to be the case. What does this parameter do?

Here is a code snippet:

```
  5 void testfn (std::ios::event ev, std::ios_base& stream, int index)
  6 {
  7   switch (ev)
  8   {
  9     case stream.copyfmt_event:
 10       std::cout << "copyfmt_event\n"; break;
 11     case stream.imbue_event:
 12       std::cout << "imbue_event\n"; break;
 13     case stream.erase_event:
 14       std::cout << "erase_event\n"; break;
 15   }
 16 }
 17
 18 void testfn2 (std::ios::event ev, std::ios_base& stream, int index)
 19 {
 20   switch (ev)
 21   {
 22     case stream.copyfmt_event:
 23       std::cout << "copyfmt_event 2\n"; break;
 24     case stream.imbue_event:
 25       std::cout << "imbue_event 2\n"; break;
 26     case stream.erase_event:
 27       std::cout << "erase_event 2\n"; break;
 28   }
 29 }
 30
 31 int main () {
 32   std::ofstream filestr;
 33   filestr.register_callback (testfn,0);
 34   filestr.register_callback (testfn2,1);
 35   filestr.imbue (std::cout.getloc());
 36
 37   std::ofstream filestr2;
 38   filestr2.register_callback (testfn,1);
 39   filestr2.register_callback (testfn2,0);
 40   filestr2.imbue (std::cout.getloc());
 41   return 0;
 42 }
```

Here's the output:

```
jefferson@ubuntu:~/inheritance$ g++ -std=c++14 stream_callbacks.cpp
jefferson@ubuntu:~/inheritance$ ./a.out
imbue_event 2
imbue_event
imbue_event 2
imbue_event
erase_event 2
erase_event
erase_event 2
erase_event
```

Comment: _"index - custom parameter which will be passed to the function"_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/register_callback .  So just a value you get back when called.

Comment: From the page you linked, *If more than one callback function is registered, they are all called, in the inverse order of registration.*

Comment: @chris Thanks, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: @RichardCritten can you give me an example of how that could be useful?

Comment: @JeffersonHudson, cppreference gives an example of it being the index returned by `xalloc`, so you can use it to retrieve custom data from the stream. Not that very many people actually use any of this, but it's there.

Answer (score 0):

I have a library ([libaddr](https://github.com/m2osw/libaddr)) which makes use of of that.

When outputting a vector of addresses, my code will default to the comma (",") as the default separator:

```
addr::addr::vector_t addresses;

...define the addresses somehow...

std::cout << addresses;  // defaults to commas between each address
```

However, you may want a space or a newline instead:

```
std::cout << addr::setaddrsep(" ") << addresses;

std::cout << addr::setaddrsep("\n") << addresses;
```

Here I show how you use a structure and a function to change the separator as shown above (most of that source is in [addr.h](https://github.com/m2osw/libaddr/blob/main/libaddr/addr.h), see the [addr.cpp](https://github.com/m2osw/libaddr/blob/main/libaddr/addr.cpp) for the `xalloc()` call):

```
struct _setaddrsep
{
    std::string     f_sep;
};

template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
inline std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits> &
operator << (std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits> & out, _setaddrsep sep)
{
    int const index(get_ostream_index());
    _ostream_info * info(static_cast<_ostream_info *>(out.pword(index)));
    if(info == nullptr)
    {
        info = new _ostream_info;
        out.pword(index) = info;
        out.register_callback(basic_stream_event_callback, index);
    }
    info->f_sep = sep.f_sep;
    return out;
}
```

As we can see, I have a call `get_ostream_index()` which returns the index you mentioned. The following function calls the `xalloc()` function once for my `libaddr` environment. After that, the index remains the same for the entire run of the program. In other words, this index is assigned by the `ios_base` library to your class.

```
int get_ostream_index()
{
    cppthread::guard lock(*cppthread::g_system_mutex);

    if(!g_ostream_index_allocated)
    {
        g_ostream_index_allocated = true;
        g_ostream_index = std::ios_base::xalloc();
    }

    return g_ostream_index;
}
```

**WARNING:** you may be tempted to write `int g_ostream_index = xalloc();` to directly initialize your global variable. This is dangerous for at least two reasons: (1) you cannot be 100% sure that `xalloc()` can be called that early (probably, though); (2) if you have another global function where an output stream is used, `g_ostream_index` may not yet be initialized (i.e. in C++ you do not control in which order the globals are initialized). With a function, you can be sure it happens in order. Also, if you write a .so or .DLL, the initialization will happen before your own program initialization, so you are safe as long as the library does not itself include another global that would attempt to use the `g_ostream_index`. Personally, I prefer to be safe than sorry. These is a kind of bug that can be hard to debug because it happens before `main()` gets called.

*Later* when an address is printed, it can check whether a user specified parameter was found:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _ContainerT>
inline typename std::enable_if<
          std::is_same<_ContainerT, addr::vector_t>::value
                || std::is_same<_ContainerT, addr::set_t>::value
        , std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>>::type &
operator << (std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits> & out, _ContainerT const & addresses)
{
    std::string sep(",");
    _ostream_info * info(static_cast<_ostream_info *>(out.pword(get_ostream_index())));
    if(info != nullptr)
    {
        sep = info->f_sep;
    }

    bool first(true);
    for(auto const & a : addresses)
    {
        if(first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            out << sep;
        }
        out << a;
    }
    return out;
}
```

As we can see, I set a variable named `sep` to a default separator `","`. Then I check the `out.pword(index)` and if not `nullptr`, then  I replace `sep` with the user defined separator.

Here is my `_ostream_info` structure which includes two parameters:

```
struct _ostream_info
{
    addr::string_ip_t   f_mode = addr::string_ip_t::STRING_IP_ALL;
    std::string         f_sep = std::string(",");
};
```

I think that 99.9% of the time, you should use a pointer to a structure just so that way you can add any number of parameters as time passes without having to edit all your stream functions to go from a `long` to a pointer (i.e. you can always have a `long` in your structure to start with).

Another important point: the callback is very important if you use the `pword()` feature because in that case you allocate memory which must be freed with the callback when it receives the `std::ios_base::erase_event` event.

The `copy_fmt` must also be implemented to make sure that it duplicates your buffer (or uses a refcount of some sort).

---

Of course, in your examples, the callbacks with index 0 and index 1 are not yours. These two calls are likely to smash the system defined callbacks (i.e. you most certainly only have one callback per index). Since my `xalloc()` returns 2, I would imagine that 0 and 1 are already system defined and that's certainly why your calls are seemingly working.